# Python: How to split strings with no commas or spaces

Tags: python, string

I want to be able to split a string that just contains letters into separate letters. From the code I have below; I expected the variable `f` to contain `['a','b']` but it did not. Any ideas as to how I might fix this problem?

```
a = "bc"
f = a.split()
print(f)
```

output:

```
['bc']
```

Answer (score 5):

In that case you do not have to split: a string is iterable over **its characters**, so you can simply use:

```
f = list(a)
```

This will construct a list such that *every* character in the string is an element in the resulting list:

```
>>> a="foobar"
>>> f=list(a)
>>> f
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
```

Comment: ah, thanks a ton dude!

Comment: Which also means there's a good chance you don't need to turn it into a list in the first place.

Comment: @ThijsvanDien: indeed, although I've seen it is usually done to have a way to manipulate the string char-by-char and then `join` it back into a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you try by direction iteration then:

```
x=[i for i in a]
```

now analyzing its time with respect to that for `list(a)`;

```
tarptaeya@TARPTAEYA:~$ python -m timeit "a='foobar';x=[i for i in a]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.443 usec per loop
tarptaeya@TARPTAEYA:~$ python -m timeit "a='foobar';list(a)"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.385 usec per loop
```

hence splitting using `list()` method  is more efficient method compared to first .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get only letter.

```
>>> val = 'abcdefg 12'
>>> [item for item in list(val) if item.isalpha()]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Another solution:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x.isalpha(), list(val))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```